# Create a process in java which stays alive always

Tags: java

I create class to execute CMD command continuously It is working fine for the first iteration in the below code, but the problem is the process is died after one iteration is done

```
class CommandLine{
    
    
    Process Handle ;
    OutputStreamWriter writer;
    Scanner getCommand;
    Socket socket;
    
    public CommandLine(Socket socket) throws IOException {
        this.socket = socket;
        

        
    }
    public void executeCommand() {
        try {
            
            getCommand = new Scanner(socket.getInputStream()).useDelimiter("\\A");
            Handle = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe").redirectErrorStream(true).start();
            while(getCommand.hasNextLine()) {
                
                try(PrintWriter stdin = new PrintWriter(Handle.getOutputStream())) {

                    stdin.write(getCommand.nextLine()+System.lineSeparator());
                    stdin.flush();
                }
                if(Handle.getInputStream().read()>0) {
                    Scanner result = new Scanner(Handle.getInputStream()).useDelimiter("\\A");
                    while(result.hasNextLine()) {
                        System.out.print(result.nextLine()+"\n");

                    }
                }
            }
            
            
           
            
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 

    }
    
}
```

thx for response

Comment: I don't see a daemon thread anywhere.  You should create and start one.

Answer (score 0):

You need to re-organise your code. The sub-process dies because you've got a try with resources block inside the loop:

```
try(PrintWriter stdin = new PrintWriter(Handle.getOutputStream())) {

    stdin.write(getCommand.nextLine()+System.lineSeparator());
    stdin.flush();
}
```

The above means STDIN of the sub-process ends after one line, and so does the CMD.EXE.

Also note that just moving `PrintWriter stdin` part outside the loop isn't enough. You won't be able to reliably supply the STDIN and read STDOUT in same loop as the STDOUT might be many lines of input and block the process when you write STDIN.

The fix is easy: follow @VGR suggestion and replace `.redirectErrorStream(true)` by either `.redirectOutput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT)` or `.inheritIO()`
which will mean that you don't need to read `getInputStream()`. Alternatively use a background thread for your code either for the write to STDIN or for read from `getInputStream()` / STDOUT.

Comment: In this particular case, there is no need for threads;  since the output of the child process is just being printed, the second loop can be removed entirely, and in its place, `redirectOutput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT)` can be called on the ProcessBuilder before the process is started.

Comment: @VGR Good point, though I avoid using INHERIT as it does not seem to work via `jshell` - such as `new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe","/c","dir").redirectOutput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT).start().waitFor();`. Works inside `main()`, but not in jshell of Windows (or Linux with bash -c). Any idea why it doesn't work in `jshell`?

Comment: I don’t use jshell much, so I honestly don’t know.  Perhaps it uses a raw console output mode or something, instead of regular stdout.